# I am creating an application in windows form

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I want to add labels through loop

```
`private void CourseOutcomes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            studentDetails dets = new studentDetails();
            dets.ShowDialog();
            name=dets.CourseName;
            labelCourseName.Text = name;
            string id = dets.CourseValue;
            SqlDataReader sdr = bznessLogic.GetQuestions(id);
            List<Label> lbl = new List<Label>();
            int count = 0;
            while (sdr.Read()) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("s");

                lbl[count] = new Label();
                lbl[count].Text = sdr[0].ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(lbl[count]);
                count++;
            }
            sdr.Close();
        }`
```

But it keeps giving error
'Index was out of range.

Should I initiablize it diffrently or..

Comment: There is no label at index 0 when you start. You have to create it and add it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I just needed to initialize it properly which I expected, noob mistake but here we are.

```
private void CourseOutcomes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            studentDetails dets = new studentDetails();
            dets.ShowDialog();
            name=dets.CourseName;
            labelCourseName.Text = name;
            string id = dets.CourseValue;
            SqlDataReader sdr = bznessLogic.GetQuestions(id);
            List<Label> lbl = new List<Label>();
            int count = 0;
            while (sdr.Read()) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("s");
                lbl.Add(new Label() { Name="lbl"+count});
                lbl[count].Text = sdr[0].ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(lbl[count]);
                count++;
            }
            sdr.Close();
        }
```